# How do I add 7 images in a row html & css

Tags: html, css

How do I fit 7 images in a row using purely HTML & CSS with no added Jquery or JavaScript?

I did not yet try this but I would like to know as this is for an upcoming project

Comment: Give them a CSS `width` of `calc(100%/7)`. Also parent should probably have `white-space:nowrap`

Comment: take a look at css flexbox

Comment: I think it's better for you to learn it by yourself for upcoming projects too

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using grid or flex which are two popular layout systems. Personally i would use grid since it's easier to for example have equal sized childs compared to flex imo. I think many developers nowadays will also prefer using grid instead of flex to stuff like this.

HTML

```
  <div class="grid-container">
   <img src="..." alt="" /> 
   <img src="..." alt="" /> 
   <img src="..." alt="" /> 
   <img src="..." alt="" />
   <img src="..." alt="" /> 
   <img src="..." alt="" /> 
   <img src="..." alt="" /> 
   <img src="..." alt="" /> 
  </div>
```

Css

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 100px) 
}
```

If you want to use flex then you can use `flex: 1` on the childs, but in some cases the child wont be equally sized.